# .NET 8 Blazor stream rendering not working on Azure App Service

Tags: .net, azure, blazor, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET 8 Blazor app running with no interactivity enabled (SSR). When running locally stream rendering works as expected and partially updates the UI when a variable changes on form submit. I have now deployed the app to an Azure App Service via GitHub actions and stream rendering has stopped working - the page hangs without updating the UI until to form submission is complete.

The attribute added to my page:

```
@page "/contact"

@attribute [StreamRendering]
```

The content that should update on variable change:

```
<button type="@Type" disabled="@IsLoading"
        class="border-0 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 bg-black px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow hover:bg-gray-800 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-gray-600 disabled:bg-gray-800 disabled:cursor-progress">
    @if (IsLoading)
    {
        <LoadingSpinner Size="LoadingSpinnerSize.Small"/>
    }
    else
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "button";

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsLoading { get; set; }

}
```

My program file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>();

app.Run();
```

My `App.razor` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base href="/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
    <HeadOutlet/>
</head>

<body class="bg-black font-mono text-slate-50 min-h-screen antialiased">
<Routes/>
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The browser dev tools after making a successful POST:
[image: browser dev tools]

Comment: My control test would be to deploy the standard Template with the StreamRendering Weather Page.  That will tell you if it's your code or the Azure App Service.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I can confirm that it also doesn't work with the standard template when navigating to the weather page via nav. However it does seem to work when refreshing the weather page.

Comment: Can you show your app.razor in the question?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis updated the question with App.razor

Comment: Did you open the dev-tools and looked in the Console and Network windows?  That would be my first action.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes I have. There is nothing out of the ordinary there, just stream rendering not working. I've updated my question.

Comment: If it doesn't work on the standard template then put an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Comment: @Beau -  If possible can you share your GitHub repo?

Comment: @Harshitha unfortunately not as it is a private company repo. The fact that the default template also has issues points to a wider problem with app service though no?

Comment: @Beau Did you use interactive render mode as server or webassembly?

Comment: @SirraSneha I'm not using and interactive render modes.